# OR-TOOLS - how to solve ordered allocation problem?

Tags: or-tools, constraint-programming, cp-sat

I have 'n' tables and I have 'm' boxes.
The job is to stack all the boxes on tables.

Question:
what are the different possible combinations?
important note: all the boxes are ordered when put on a table, like stacks. I need to know the rank of each box in the stack.

how to implement that problem with ORTOOL constraint programming / SAT?
what is the best strategy? what variables / constraints?

(I dont expect code, but just advices... unless you are a fast developer :)
Thanks

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model

class VarArraySolutionPrinter(cp_model.CpSolverSolutionCallback):

    def __init__(self, variables):
        cp_model.CpSolverSolutionCallback.__init__(self)
        self.__variables = variables
        self.__solution_count = 0

    def on_solution_callback(self):
        self.__solution_count += 1
        for v in self.__variables:
            print('%s=%i' % (v, self.Value(v)))

        print("")

    def solution_count(self):
        return self.__solution_count


def main():

    variables = []
    model = cp_model.CpModel()

    #################################################
    
    nb_tables = 3
    nb_boxes = 4

    for box in range(nb_boxes):
        box_to_table = model.NewIntVar(0, nb_tables - 1, 'box_'+str(box)+'_to_table')
        variables.append(box_to_table)

    ranking_variables = []

    for box in range(nb_boxes):
        rank_of_box_on_its_table = model.NewIntVar(0, nb_boxes - 1, 'rank_of_box_'+str(box)+'_on_its_table')
        variables.append(rank_of_box_on_its_table)
        ranking_variables.append(rank_of_box_on_its_table)

    # the next line is not good because the ranking is global
    # and not local to each table. how to manage that?
    model.AddAllDifferent(ranking_variables)

    #################################################

    solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
    solution_printer = VarArraySolutionPrinter(variables)
    status = solver.SearchForAllSolutions(model, solution_printer)

    print('Status = %s' % solver.StatusName(status))
    print('Number of solutions found: %i' % solution_printer.solution_count())


main()
```

And with the boolean version:

```
#################################################
    
    nb_tables = 3
    nb_boxes = 4

    for box in range(nb_boxes):

        this_box_vars = []

        for table in range(nb_tables):
            box_in_table = model.NewBoolVar('box_'+str(box)+'_in_table_' + str(table))
            variables.append(box_in_table)
            this_box_vars.append(box_in_table)

        model.Add(sum(this_box_vars) == 1)

    ranking_variables = []

    for box in range(nb_boxes):
        rank_of_box_on_its_table = model.NewIntVar(0, nb_boxes - 1, 'rank_of_box_'+str(box)+'_on_its_table')
        variables.append(rank_of_box_on_its_table)
        ranking_variables.append(rank_of_box_on_its_table)

    # the next line is not good because the ranking is global
    # and not local to each table. how to manage that?
    model.AddAllDifferent(ranking_variables)

    #################################################
```

Comment: CP-SAT, and a lot of Boolean variables.

Comment: Thanks Laurent! well, booleans are not going to give me the ranking on the stack... or you have a trick here?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use integer variables.

Rule of the thumb:

- if you see an AllDifferent constraint, remove it, and replace the integer variable by a list of Boolean variables.
- Add Sum(bool_vars) == 1

`x[i][j][k]` is a Boolean variable indicating that box i is on table j at position k.

`y[j][k]` indicates if a box in on table j at position k.

each box appears exactly once:

```
forall i: Sum on j, k box[i][j][k] == 1
```

each position is occupied by at most one box:

```
forall j, k: sum on i box[i][k][k] <= 1
```

if a box is somewhere, it means this somewhere is occupied:

```
forall i, j, k: box[i][j][k] implies y[j][k]
```

if a position is occupied, there must be a box at this position:

```
forall j, k: bool_or([y[j][k].Not(), box[0][j][k], .., box[n - 1][j][k]])
```

positions must be densely occupied starting from 0 on a table:

```
forall j, k (except last position): y[j][k].Not() implies y[j][k + 1].Not()
```

If you want the rank of a box

```
forall i: rank[i] == sum over j, k box[i][j][k] * k
```

Comment: I implemented your advice... but still, how to compute that ranking? Thanks Laurent!

Comment: count the one before you ?

Comment: I am sorry, i dont see how to do that on a simple way

Comment: please describe exactly your problem and at least one solution.

Comment: Wow ! Thanks Laurent! Great! the problem looks simple but the way to implement it is not!